# Any example of integrating the activiti plugin with grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, activiti

Please provide any link for integrating the activiti plugin with grails. I looked into the vacation request, so apart from that any other will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think [Grails Activiti Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/activiti) might be what you are looking for though i am not exactly sure about your requirment.

This is another forum with detailed discussion on [Grails and Activiti integration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-activiti-plugin/BdhGd3TZww8)